# How do you graph two variables from a .csv file as two lines in ggplot2?

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2, linear-regression, linegraph

I have imported a .csv file and have plotted my data points on a line graph. But I am attempting to compare male and female life expectancies, but I can't figure out how to plot one line for males and one for females.

Here is an example of part of my data (ALE stands for average life expectancy).

```
Year    Sex ALE
1900    Female  48.3
1900    Male    46.6
1901    Female  50.6
1901    Male    48
1902    Female  53.4
1902    Male    50.2
1903    Female  52
1903    Male    49.5
1904    Female  49.1
1904    Male    46.6
1905    Female  50.2
1905    Male    47.6
```

This is the code I have thus far. Ultimately I will put my work into a .rmd file.

```
library(ggplot2) # call up ggplot2
library(RColorBrewer) # call up rcolorbrewer palette
options(scipen = 999) # remove scientific notation
sex <- read.csv("~/Big Data IBP/Life expectancy_sex.csv") # data focusing on life expectancy comparing sex. #male v. female
# run test to see how year of death has changed over the years
ggplot(data = sex, aes(x = Year, y = ALE)) +
  geom_line(linetype = "solid", col = "Blue", size = 0.5, arrow = arrow()) +
  labs(
    title = "Average Life Expectancy Based on Sex",
    subtitle = "1900-2014", x = "Year", y = "Age at Death"
  )
```

The issue is I want to have one line for males and one for females to compare the 2 lines on one graph. But the actual result I have is one line on the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to map `group`, `color` and `linetype` to `aes`

```r
library(ggplot2) # call up ggplot2
options(scipen = 999) # remove scientific notation

df <- read.table(text = "Year    Sex ALE
1900    Female  48.3
1900    Male    46.6
1901    Female  50.6
1901    Male    48
1902    Female  53.4
1902    Male    50.2
1903    Female  52
1903    Male    49.5
1904    Female  49.1
1904    Male    46.6
1905    Female  50.2
1905    Male    47.6",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# run test to see how year of death has changed over the years
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Year, y = ALE, 
                      group = Sex, color = Sex, linetype = Sex)) +
  geom_line(size = 0.5, arrow = arrow()) +
  labs(
    title = "Average Life Expectancy Based on Sex",
    subtitle = "1900-2014", x = "Year", y = "Age at Death"
  ) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! How does the script change (like in the first part of this) if I am using a .csv file? The full data is between 1900-2014.

Comment: You just have to replace `df` in my code with the name of data frame e.g., `sex` in your original example

Comment: See [this](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-essentials) to learn more about `ggplot2`

Comment: How would you adjust this to make a histogram?

Comment: @emily123: see the link I posted earlier

Comment: @emily123: can you post as a separate question? You'll get more responses